# How to identify sites that don't meet criteria?

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

How do you select sites from a data frame that don't meet certain criteria in another data frame?

In my example I have two Sites (1 & 2) which have variables (a, b, c & d) that is associated with them. However, Site 2 is missing variables c & d.

```
  Site = c(1,1,1,1,2,2),
  variable = c('a','b','c','d','a','b'))
```

I'm interested in finding sites that are missing a defined set of variables. My selected variables are here:

```
sel <- data.frame(variable = c('a','b','c'))
```

I'm trying to get this:

```
Site  variable
2     c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each `site` you can `complete` the missing combination of `variable` and use `anti_join` with original `df` to get the ones which are missing.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  tidyr::complete(Site, variable = sel$variable) %>%
  anti_join(df)

#  Site variable
#  <dbl> <chr>   
#1     2 c
```

Comment: Awesome - thank you. I'm liking this complete function.